# Aspx aplication dialog pages(or #dialogiframe) fails to load on chrome/chromePortable with chromedriver 76 through selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Aspx aplication dialog pages(or #dialogiframe) fails to load on chrome/chromePortable with chromedriver 76 through selenium. When we open any dialog pages in aspx application it opens blank page and selenium fails with NoSuchElement Found exception. However, we tried this manually on same browser versions and it loads perfectly manually.
It happens only when we launch out browser using chrome driver 75+.

**Browser:** Chrome/ChromePortable 76
**Chrome Driver Version :** 75.x and higher
**Selenium Version :**  3.13
**Language :** C#

We tried with making w3c false in C# with selenium but it doesn't work because of existing issue : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7521

It seems style = 'height:fit-content' blocking the page to load. when we removed the style or changed the style it worked.

```
    var frame = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("dialog[open]:last-of-type #dialogiframe")).UnwrapAllLayers();
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
    var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td[style = 'height:fit-content']"));
    var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style=''", element);
```